# Stripe Terminal server environment

Tags: node.js, electron, stripe-payments

I am attempting to use the Stripe terminal using their npm package located [here](https://github.com/stripe/terminal-js). I am currently attempting on using it through an Electron app since it is what I am using for my payment Point of Sale (POS). Whenever I attempt to run the `loadStripeTerminal` function, I get a `null` returned, which is expected, according to the documentation, "if you call loadStripeTerminal in a server environment it will resolve to null". I have looked throughout the internet and asked friends, but I have not been able to find what would I use as a "non-server" environment to run my terminal through.

The relevant code is shown as follows:

```
const { loadStripeTerminal } = require('@stripe/terminal-js');

/* Other non-relevant functions skipped */

async function setupStripe() {
  const StripeTerminal = await loadStripeTerminal();
}

setupStripe();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The way Terminal works usually is you have a web page that runs the Stripe Terminal JS library (which that package is a wrapper around). That page connects to the phsyical reader and sends it commands to process payments. You also have a backend server(running on your premises or the cloud or a VPS or wherever), which runs your backend software(PHP or NodeJS or Java or whatever you use)+Stripe's API libraries, and it calls Stripe's API to get 'connection tokens' you pass to the frontend to use in connecting to the reader.

Comment: The references to server environment just mean, don't try to run that frontend Stripe Terminal JS library on a server(like a NodeJS backend), it's intended to run a web browser. 
As for it being null here, I don't know enough about Electron to say if that is a front or backend or how close it is to a browser!

Comment: I'd probably start by looking at the devtools console for your Electron app and see if there's an error being thrown at the time loadStripeTerminal is called. My guess is something in https://github.com/stripe/terminal-js/blob/14e88397ac0751fd001f66d96c8de791ca60301c/src/shared.ts doesn't work in Electron(as I said I know nothing about Electron, and Stripe doesn't document if this library is meant to work in that environment or not so maybe it doesn't)